# Can Javascript inheritance be done this way? It works but is it a right way?

Tags: javascript

This is the parent class

```
function Person(name,age)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.age =age;
    this.alertAge = function(){
        alert(age)
    };
    this.alertName = function(){
        alert(this.name)
    }
    this.setName = function(name){
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

This is the Level 1 child class

```
function Student(name,age,id){
    this.id = id;
    Person.call(this,name,age);
}
```

This is the Level 2 child class

```
function IStudent(name,age,id,children)
{
    this.children = children;
    Student.call(this,name,age,id)
}
```

This is the Level 1 child object

```
let s1 = new Student('Jacob',21,1001);
console.log(s1)
```

This is the Level 2 child object

```
let s2 = new IStudent('Jonathan',28,1002,1);
console.log(s2)
s2.setName('Ramoji');
console.log(s2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the prototype chain

You need to add these lines to your code :

```
Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;
```

and

```
IStudent.prototype = Object.create(Student.prototype);
IStudent.prototype.constructor = IStudent;
```

So you can re-write your code like this :

```
Person.prototype.alertAge = function() {
    alert(this.age);
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand what goes wrong if i leave out the prototype chain.For ex: s2.setName function works fine here. I am able to create children and instantiate them, call parent functions etc which confuses me because i thought none of that would work without the prototype chain.

Comment: What you did works because you don't declare your functions `setName`, `alertName` in the prototype object. In fact you don't really use inheritance, by calling the Person's constructor, you just affect some object variables using keyword `this`, nothing more...

Comment: Why is this not inheritance? I am trying to understand what I would miss by doing it like this. At what point would I not get some feature of inheritance ?

Comment: If you add something into the Person's prototype object, it will not be accessible from the Student.

Answer (score 0):

Look this link : 
http://javascript.info/tutorial/inheritance
Class Inheritance Using Prototype
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oNWNlMrkpc

you can see the book JavaScript Web Applications (O'Reilly)
Or in french this book : JavaScript_pour_le_Web_2.0